# Characterize $|\nabla f|$ as minimal function which satisfies an upper gradient inequality

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $f \in C^1( \mathbb R^n, \mathbb R) .$
Then one by chain rule has
$$ (*)\qquad |f(g(1))-f(g(0))| \leq \int_0^1 |\nabla f|(g_t)|g'(t) |\ dt, \quad \forall g \in C^1([0,1],\mathbb R^n). $$
I have heard in a lecture that $|\nabla f|$ can actually be characterized as the smallest continuous function for which $(*)$ holds. Is this true? How can I show it?

Comment: Consider the pair of points $a$ and $a+t\nabla f(a)$ where $t$ is small.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thank you! (I would upvote you if I could...)